# Need help with this integral using trig identities

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration, fourier-series

I am trying to integrate the function $$\int_{-\pi/2}^0  \sin(2x)\cos(nx) \, \mathrm{d} x.$$

My professor has an answer of $$\frac{-2\cos(\frac{n \pi}{2})+1}{n^{2}-4}.$$

When I do this problem, I first notice that it can be broken into its trig identity and the new integral is written as 
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^0  \sin((2+n)x \, \mathrm{d} x + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^0  \sin((2-n)x \, \mathrm{d} x$$

Once I integrate both of these, I end up getting 
$$\frac{-1}{2+n}\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{(2+n)\pi}{2}\right)\right]+\frac{-1}{2-n}\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{(2-n)\pi}{2}\right)\right]$$

I can't seem to manipulate the above equation to get what my professor got

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos\left(\frac{(2\pm n)\pi}2\right)=\cos(\pi\pm \frac{n\pi}2)=-\cos\frac{n\pi}2$$ as $\cos(\pi\pm y)=\cos y\cos\pi\mp\sin y\sin\pi=-\cos y$ using $\cos(A\pm B)=\cos A\cos B\mp\sin A\sin B$ and $\cos\pi=-1,\sin\pi=0$

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is [$$2\frac{1+\cos(\frac{n \pi}{2})}{n^{2}-4}.$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Asin%282x%29cos%28nx%29%20dx%2F%2F%5D%20from%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3Ax%2F%2F%5D%3D%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A-pi%2F2%2F%2F%5D%20to%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A0%2F%2F%5D)
After integrate you should get $$\dfrac12\left\{\frac{-1}{2+n}\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{(2+n)\pi}{2}\right)\right]+\frac{-1}{2-n}\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{(2-n)\pi}{2}\right)\right]\right\}.$$
The rest is in lab bhattacharjee's answer.